# specify same width for certain columns using xltabular

Tags: latex, width

I am creating a table using the code below with 5 columns (first column is wider with long text but the others are not).

How can I adapt the code below to specify the exact same width for columns #2, #3, #4 and #5? The column #1 should have the width of the longest text in the cell. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}  
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} lllll @{}}

\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}%
{Table \thetable, continued from previous page} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\

\addlinespace 
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\ 
%\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns 2 thru 5 of your table will need to be quite narrow. To allow LaTeX to hyphenate words, including the very first words, in the respective cells , I suggest you change

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
```

to

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
```

In addition, I'd like to suggest that you replace

```
\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} lllll @{}}
```

with

```
\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} l LLLL @{}}
```

That way, columns 2 thru 5 are guaranteed to have the same (narrow) width.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{xltabular}{\mylen}{@{} l LLLL @{}}

\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}%
{Table \thetable, continued from previous page} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxx xxxx xxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxx} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Year & 2017 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Mon & 30 June 2000 & xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx \\

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Organisation & Year & 1999/2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx x & Organisation & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx/xxx xxxxxxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Geography & xxx/xx xxxxxxxxx xxxx & 30 June 2000 & xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Geography & xxxxxxx xxxxxx & 2011 & xxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & February 2000 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q3 & xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Organisation & Mon & 1 July 2010 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx & Organisation & Quarter & 2011/2012 Q4 & xxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Organisation & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx & Individual & Day & 30 June 2000 & xxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx & Individual & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx & 1999 & xxxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx'sxxxxxx xxx & Individual & Year & 1999 & xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx \\
%\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```